# It is advisable to use where() multiple times in a List, Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

It is advisable to use where() multiple times in a List?
For example,

```
List result = someList.where((element)=> predicate_1).toList().where((element)=> predicate_2).toList();
```

Or is there an easy way to filter out all entries that satisfy predicate_1, predicate_2, .. predicate_n?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can combine values inside one where body

```dart
list.where((element){
  return element.value1 == sth && element.value2 == sthmr;
})
```

you can just expand on this.

Answer (score 1):

Stacked wheres are not as fast as using a single where, whenever it's possible.

```dart
void main() {
  final List<int> v = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    v.add(1);
  }
  final tik = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  v.where((i) => i == 1 * 2).where((i) => i == 1 * 2).where((i) => i == 1 * 2);
  final tok = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  print(tok - tik);

 print("______*________*_______*");

  final new_tik = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  v.where((i) => i == 1 * 2 &&  i == 1 * 2 &&  i == 1 * 2);
  final new_tok = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  print(new_tok - new_tik);
}
```

```
1091
______*________*_______*
76
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Burak wrote, or you can chain the `.where()`. Note that you don't have to add a `.toList()` between each. So this is fine:

```
List result = someList.where((element) => predicate_1).where((element) => predicate_2).toList();
```